# Django: Can you upload a directory or multiple files in Admin site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

You can upload an individual file with the Admin site. However I have a need to upload at least 1 file, but potentially multiple files, for each object. Sometimes there will be sub-directories with these files that must also be uploaded.

Is there a good way to do this in the Admin site? Or would you recommend simply sftp-ing the files across and storing the path to them?

Thank you for your help.

I've only very recently starting working with Django, so do not yet know all the cool features I could be using :-)

Comment: Are you referring to an FileField on your model, or more about a general filemanager?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have a look at https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer, it allows multiple files to be uploaded at once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For the sake of simplicity I've settled for the nice and reliable sFTP option though.